# Byte Patching using winrt api (C++)

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime

I want to write a C++ program that will be compiled into a dll and be injected into a C++ uwp app.

This program should patch bytes at certain address.
For example We want to patch address `0x12345678` with `{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}` for certain purposes.

I wrote a simple programm using normal windows apis for it:

```
void PatchMemory(LPVOID address, BYTE* data, SIZE_T size) {
    DWORD oldProtect;
    int result;

    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    if (hProcess == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        Log::Warning("Patch unsuccessful...");
        return;
    }

    result = VirtualProtect(address, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    if (result != 0) {
        Log::Warning("Patch unsuccessful... code: {}", result);
        return;
    }

    result = WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), address, data, size, nullptr);
    if (result != 0) {
        Log::Warning("Patch unsuccessful... code: {}", result);
        return;
    }

    result = VirtualProtect(address, size, oldProtect, &oldProtect);
    if (result != 0) {
        Log::Warning("Patch unsuccessful... code: {}", result);
        return;
    }

    Log::Info("Patch successful!");
}
```

But the sad thing now is... I can't use these apis in my dll because they don't work in the sandboxed uwp environment of the program in which the dll will be injected.

Now I wanted to know:

- Is it possible to do byte patching with winrt apis?
- If so, how?
- Might there be other solutions for my problem?

I wish y'all humans a good day and hope this problem can be solved soon...

EDIT:

**This is not for malicious purposes. This is for modding Minecraft Bedrock Edition and increasing the building height limit of the nether.**

Comment: to mod Minecraft and increase the building height in the nether

Comment: You might run into this though [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). So memory patching is probably going to be fragile. Maybe you should ask around on minecraft forums or look for a mod that already does this.